# Numpy fancy indexing and assignment

Tags: python, indexing, numpy

Normally numpy forces the left and right side of an assignment to match, so for example if I do `a[:] = b`, `b` must be the same shape or broadcast to the same shape as `a`. But there seems to be an exception to that rule:

```
>>> a = np.arange(10)
>>> a
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
>>> b = a.copy()
>>> a[[0,1,2]] = b[::2]
>>> a
array([0, 2, 4, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
>>> a[np.arange(10)] = b[:2]
>>> a
array([0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1])
```

It seems to only work with 1d arrays and only if there is fancy indexing on the left side of the assignment, but I haven't been able to find documentation for this behavior anywhere. Is this behavior documented, if so where, and also can someone give an example of when it might be useful?

Update:

It seems that the numpy flatiter type behaves this way too, is there some connection between flatiter and fancy indexing that I don't know about?

```
>>> a.flat = [10,11]
>>> a
array([10, 11, 10, 11, 10, 11, 10, 11, 10, 11])
>>> a.flat[:] = [2,3,4]
>>> a
array([2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 2])
>>> a.flat = range(100)
>>> a
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

Comment: You correctly described this feature -- it is only allowed when doing assignments in combination with advanced indexing on one-dimensional arrays.  While I'm sure I read about this in the docs, I can't find a link at the moment.  I found this useful now and then, though I think it would have been better if this were supported by a dedicated function and regular assignments would still give an error.

Comment: Right, I quickly assumed it was just broadcasting but I see now that it doesn't actually meet the requirements for broadcasting! Weird!

Comment: I'm unsure whether it is a feature or a bug... at least, http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/internals.code-explanations.html#getting-or-setting seems not to mention this as a special case.

Comment: Other interesting cases I was playing with..  source smaller `a[[0,1,2]] = [-1, -2]` (it loops), source bigger `a[[0,1,2]] = [-1, -2, -3, -4]` (it halts), and destination repeats `a[[0,0,1]] = [-1, -2, -3]` (it seems to iterate on the source.  wreaks havoc with `+=` operator here).

Comment: @wim, the [0, 0, 1] case is a separate issue which, for better or for worse, is a design choice the numpy folks are aware of and have no intention of changing. http://www.scipy.org/FAQ#head-1ed851e9aff803d41d3cded8657b2b15a888ebd5

Comment: Thanks for the input everyone, I can see how this might be useful but I agree with @SvenMarnach, I'd prefer to have this feature live in a function.

Comment: Is there any way to disable this "feature"?  I'd rather have it raise an exception by default than its current behavior.

Comment: @Bago, as the FAQ explains, the [0,0,1] case not a numpy design choice. It's something forced on us by Python's semantics.

Comment: @RobertKern (sorry for my last comment I'm not on it today) you're right, maybe "limitation" is a better phrase than "design choice"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this behavior is modeled on R and its ancestor S/S-plus. That's how list assignment ("vector" assignment) works there, and it's called "recycling". The R project website talks about it, but I found a more illuminating explanation at [this link](http://www.johndcook.com/R_language_for_programmers.html#vectors). In R, a vector is a collection of measurements, so it makes sense to pad or trim it the way it does. How much of this logic has made it to numpy, and why, is still a good question.