# Disable numpy fancy indexing and assignment?

Tags: numpy

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9423984/numpy-fancy-indexing-and-assignment) identifies a "feature" that I would like to disable.
Current numpy behavior:

```
>>> a = arange(10)
>>> a[a>5] = arange(10)
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3])
```

The reason it's a problem: say I wanted an array to have two different sets of values on either side of a breakpoint (e.g., for making a "broken power-law" or some other simple piecewise function).  I might accidentally do something like this:

```
>>> x = empty(10)
>>> a = arange(10)
>>> x[a<=5] = 0 # this is fine
>>> x[a>5] = a**2 # this is not
# but what I really meant is this
>>> x[a>5] = a[a>5]**2
```

The first behavior, `x[a>5] = a**2` yields something I would consider counterintuitive - the left side and right side shapes disagree *and* the right side is not scalar, but numpy lets me do this assignment.  As pointed out on the other post, `x[5:]=a**2` is not allowed.

So, my question: is there any way to make `x[a>5] = a**2` raise an `Exception` instead of performing the assignment?  I'm very worried that I have typos hiding in my code because I never before suspected this behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of a way offhand to disable a core numpy feature. Instead of disabling the behavior you could try using np.select:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html

```
In [110]: x = np.empty(10)
In [111]: a = np.arange(10)
In [112]: x[a<=5] = 0
In [113]: x[a>5] = a**2
In [114]: x
Out[114]: array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  4.,  9.])

In [117]: condlist = [a<=5,a>5]
In [119]: choicelist=[0,a**2]
In [120]: x = np.select(condlist,choicelist)
In [121]: x
Out[121]: array([ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 36, 49, 64, 81])
```

Comment: Cool, that's a nice workaround - I'll start using it in my code now.  explicit > implicit, after all...